# Is it easy to produce hard-to-color graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, graph-colorings

This question arises from my recent visit to my daughter's second-grade class, where I led some discussion and activities on graph coloring (see [Math for seven-year-olds](http://jdh.hamkins.org/math-for-seven-year-olds-graph-coloring-chromatic-numbers-eulerian-paths/)). In one such activity, each child drew a graph as a challenge, to be colored by her partner, using the fewest possible number of colors. In another activity, the children produced maps to be 4-colored by their partners.

My question here concerns the actual computational difficulty of these tasks.

**Question.** Is it easy to come up with hard-to-color graphs? More precisely:

1. Is there a polynomial-time algorithm (in the desired number of vertices) that produces graphs $\Gamma_n$ with $n$ vertices on input $n$, such that there is no polynomial-time algorithm that computes the chromatic numbers of those graphs?
2. Is there a polynomial-time algorithm producing graphs $\Delta_n$ with $n$ vertices and stating the chromatic number $c_n$ of $\Delta_n$, such that there is no polynomial-time algorithm producing a $c_n$-coloring of $\Delta_n$?
3. Is there a polynomial-time algorithm (in the desired number of countries) that produces maps (planar graphs) of a desired size, such that there is no polynomial-time algorithm that computes 4-colorings of those maps?

Evidently, [graph-coloring is hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Computational_complexity) in general. But is it easy to produce hard instances of a desired size?

If there are affirmative answers, then one could impose further requirements, such as insisting that there is no infinite subsets of the graphs that admit a polynomial-time algorithm computing the chromatic numbers or the colorings. This would be a sense in which nearly every instance is hard.

Comment: There is a polynomial reduction from SAT to 3-coloring, I believe even for planar graphs (using gadget). So reduce a hard problem to SAT then to 3-color.

Comment: @Joro Yes, I know coloring is hard. But does your procedure answer the question? We need one graph of each size.

Comment: Joel, I believe 3-SAT with $m$ variables and $cm$ (for some explicit $c$) clauses is hard for all $m$. The encoding to coloring is $n=f(c,m)$ (believe quadratic in $m$). Pick the largest possible $m$, encode and add a bipartite graph to match $n$.

Comment: Thanks! That would aim to answer question 2. Could I ask you kindly to post an answer? Does your idea have the stronger property I mention at the end of the question?

Comment: Joel - Regarding your final comment "in which nearly every instance is hard", are there any well-known problems which are known to have this property?

Comment: Dustin, I'm not sure. When solutions display a certain coherence, it seems to me that we could expect this. For example, if you can tile a large region, then this implies an ability to tile smaller regions. So for a given set of tiles for which there is no polynomial-time tiling, every instance of $n\times n$ tiling seems hard. Could there be a polynomial time algorithm that works for infinitely many $n$? I doubt it. Tree-climbing might be another case.

Comment: suggest migrate to [cstheory.se]. the questions are closely connected with P=?NP conjecture.

Comment: @vzn I think it is on-topic here at MO. And we are getting some high-quality answers. P vs. NP issues are also on-topic here, and there are many MO users who are expert in computational complexity.

Comment: Isn't the answer to 1) "we don't know" for trivial reasons: if P = NP, then there is a polynomial time algorithm that computes the chromatic number of any graph, right?

Comment: The paper "A personal view of average-case complexity" by Impagliazzo seems relevant: cseweb.ucsd.edu/~russell/average.ps. In particular, the colorful discussion of the Gauss vs. Grouse battle is a way of formalizing the question of how easy it is to produce hard instances of problems.

Comment: @SamHopkins You are right! There is a hidden $\text{P}\neq\text{NP}$ assumption in my question. I think Emil also alluded to this issue, since I might instead have asked for NP-completeness instead merely of the absence of polynomial time solutions.

Comment: Another interesting question would be, whether humans generally also have more difficulty coloring instances, that are classified as being hard, than those, which are not (provided the size of the instances is amenable to humans).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If $n\mapsto\Gamma_n$ is a function that on input $n$ produces a graph of size $n$ in time polynomial in $n$, its range is a *sparse* polynomial-time set, meaning that it contains only polynomially many (actually, at most $1$ in this case) elements of any given size. Thus, if $n$ is given in unary, the set $X$ of pairs $(n,c)$ such that $\Gamma_n$ is $c$-colourable is a sparse NP set. If we instead give $n$ in binary, it becomes an NE set, and $X$ is computable in time polynomial in $n$ iff its binary version is in E.

Thus, a positive answer to question 1 implies $\mathrm E \ne \mathrm{NE}$, which is a stronger assumption than $\mathrm P \ne \mathrm{NP}$.

Conversely, if $\mathrm E \ne \mathrm{NE}$, let us fix a language $L$ in $\mathrm{NE}\smallsetminus\mathrm E$ consisting of binary integers. Then the set of unary encodings of elements of $L$ is in $\mathrm{NP}\smallsetminus\mathrm P$, and by the NP-completeness of 3-colourability, we can find a polynomial-time function $1^m\mapsto\Gamma'_m$ (that is, a function $m\mapsto\Gamma'_m$ computable in time polynomial in $m$) such that $m\in L$ iff $\Gamma'_m$ is 3-colourable. The size of $\Gamma'_m$ is polynomial in $m$; we can easily arrange that it is at least $m$, and a strictly increasing function of $m$. Define $\Gamma_n$ as $\Gamma'_m$ if $m\le n$ is such that $|\Gamma'_m|=n$, and (say) the empty graph if there is no such $m$. Then $\Gamma_n$ is computable in time $n^{O(1)}$, but it's 3-colourability cannot be determined by a poly-time algorithm.

Comment: I didn’t feel like explaining it in detail, but Q.2 can be answered in a similar way as Q.1. Let TFNE and FE be the exponential-time analogues of TFNP and FP. (I’ve never seen exponential search problems in the literature, so they are probably not very popular.) By usual arguments, $E\ne NE\cap coNE\to TFNE\ne FE\to TFNP\ne FP\to P\ne NP$. One can show that Q.2 is equivalent to $TFNE\ne FE$, using the fact that standard reductions of NP problems to 3-colourability also work as search problem reductions (one can recover a solution to the original problem from a colouring in polynomial time).

Answer (score 28):

Since nobody seems to have addressed question 3, I will.  The proofs of the 4-colour theorem are effective in the sense that they can be turned into polynomial-time algorithms.  So there are no planar graphs for which 4-colouring is hard.

Comment: To be more specific, you can 4-color a planar graph in time quadratic in the number of vertices: Robertson, Neil, et al. "Efficiently four-coloring planar graphs." *Proceedings 28th ACM Symposium on Theory of Computing*. ACM, 1996.

Answer (score 12):

In practice, if you want to make sure that every instance is hard, then you should look to cryptography.  For example, take two large primes, making sure to consult your cryptography textbook to avoid all the known pitfalls, and ask for a factorization of the product.  Convert this to a graph-coloring problem using the usual reductions.  If the graph doesn't have the correct number of vertices, then add a bunch of isolated vertices to pad it out.

This procedure has the advantage that every instance will actually be difficult in practice, not just that your family of instances will be asymptotically hard in the worst case.  However, the theory of non-asymptotic complexity theory is currently very underdeveloped, so we don't have any good way of stating the theoretical assumptions needed to prove that every such instance is hard.

Comment: Thanks very much! Could you link to a source for the reduction of factoring to coloring?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know of an actual reference. If I had to do it myself, I'd probably start by writing down a Boolean circuit for multiplication, which would let me express factoring as a SAT instance, and then use a standard reduction of SAT to coloring.

Comment: I like this answer, because it allows me to construct specific graph-coloring problems which are hard (we expect) for concrete reasons.

Comment: As far as I can see, this just begs the question with a different NP problem. How do you intend to generate hard instances of factoring by a polytime algorithm using only a length parameter as input? In fact, such an algorithm can *never* produce instances hard according to cryptographers’ standards, as any sparse language is trivially in P/poly.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: You're right; I have not answered the question of how to generate instances that are "hard" according to any asymptotic definition of hardness such as "NP" or "not polytime". I'm only showing how to create specific instances that are "hard" in the sense of "believed to require (say) 2^1024 bit operations in the absence of knowledge of the prime factors." This is not mathematically precise but it has the advantage of providing some practical confidence that the specific instance is "hard" rather than just being a member of an infinite family that is collectively hard.

Comment: (continued) I believe this is closer to the intuition of "producing hard instances of a desired size." No asymptotic definition of hardness can ever say that a specific instance of a specific size is "hard" in isolation since such a thing is always solvable in constant time.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins for reduction from factoring to SAT you can use the program Tough SAT (there is source too):  http://toughsat.appspot.com/

Answer (score 5):

See the following papers:

1) IF NP LANGUAGES ARE HARD ON THE WORST-CASE, THEN IT IS EASY TO FIND THEIR HARD INSTANCES, Dan Gutfreund, Ronen Shaltiel, and Amnon Ta-Shma, Journal of Computational Complexity, 2007.

2) Finding hard instances of the satisfiability problem: a survey, Cook and Mitchell, 1996-7.

Also there are some other papers that use "randomness" to generate hard instances.

Answer (score 3):

in general to prove that it is really "hard" to color *any* set of graphs (even those that could take long to generate!) is equivalent to the [P=?NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem) question and usually/often these problems stay nearly as hard even with additional information like the known chromatic number although that is a more specialized case maybe not studied as much. here are some more experimentally-derived observations that cross much research and many papers.

- there are "apparently hard instance generators" that run in P-time. one of the simplest to implement is factoring. eg a factoring algorithm can be built usually in the [SATisfiability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_satisfiability) problem most easily, and those instances can be converted to graph coloring via standard transformations (P-time). if the instances are proven hard or easy, either way is a theoretical breakthrough, and factoring is conjectured to be outside of P (and various cryptographic security systems like [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) depend on that fact). there are a few papers studying this. see eg [reducing integer factoring to NP complete problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6588/reducing-the-integer-factorization-problem-to-an-np-complete-problem) cs.se
- there is a concept of a "transition point" that seems to be applicable to all NP-complete problems, an "easy-hard-easy" transition as a parameter of the problem varies proportionally and instances are chosen ("uniformly") at random at the particular dimensions. for SAT it occurs at a clause/variable ratio. for coloring it occurs for something like edge density; SAT transition point has been studied much more however coloring transition point has been studied in a few papers. unf have not found a great survey but this [PPT / Phase transition behavior by Walsh](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~tw/phase.ppt) is excellent.

Answer (score 2):

I believe for all sufficiently large $n$ it is possible to
produce graphs on $n$ vertices for which determining
if the chromatic number is $3$ is hard via reduction
from [3-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem).

For all $m$ sufficiently large, 3-SAT with $m$ variables
and $[cm]$ clauses (for some explicit $c$) is hard and it
is possible to generate such instances in polynomial
time. There is polynomial reduction from 3-SAT to
3-COLOR where the number of vertices $n$ is $n=f(c,m)$
where $f$ is polynomial in $m$ (IIRC quadratic).

So given $n$, choose the largest $m$,
s.t. $f(c,m) \le n$, generate hard 3-SAT with $m$ variables 
and $[cm]$ clauses and encode
to 3-COLOR. Add a disjoint copy of bipartite graph
of order $ n - f(c,m) $ to make the order $n$.

---

On the other hand, I believe for randomly generated
graphs and naively generated 3-SAT, both coloring
and satisfiability would be efficient for state of
the art solvers.

---

**Added**

Joel David Hamkins asked about the proof
of hardness the SAT instances.

Maybe this can be made rigorous.

From this paper [Hard Instance Generation for SAT](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/9809117)

> define a reduction that produces, from $n$ bit FACTORING instances,
>   SAT instances in the conjunctive normal form with $O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ variables, where $\epsilon > 0$ is any fixed constant.

This gives instances of graphs of order $poly(n)$ and by adding
bipartite graphs one covers all orders $n$ sufficiently large.

Consider this game:  Joel picks integer $n$.
I find the largest $m$ such that the encoding to coloring of factoring $m$ bit
integer is on less than $n$ vertices. $n$ is polynomial in $m$.
I pick two random $m/2$ bit
primes, multiply them, encode to SAT then to COLOR and add a bipartite
graph to match $n$. Finding coloring in the graph of order $n$
will factor $m$ bit integer.

Probably something similar can be done with crypto hash
functions.

From the SAT competition I have the impression
that RANDOM SAT with the right threshold or
RANDOM SAT with forced unique solution is
hard for current state of  the art solvers.

Comment: “It is possible to generate such instances in polynomial time” = there exists a sparse NP-complete set. This is not known.

Comment: Actually, it even implies P = NP. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000082900022

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually I'm not fully clear on your procedure. Are you ultimately reducing only some instances of 3-Sat to instances of graph-coloring? If so, could you explain why those instances have the hardness property I am requesting? (And @EmilJeřábek, could you explain your remarks a little more?)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins it is evening here, will try to find references tomorrow. The SAT competition has challenge for RANDOM SAT and some solvers failed:  http://www.satcompetition.org/

Comment: @EmilJeřábek it is evening here, will try to find references tomorrow. The SAT competition has challenge for RANDOM SAT and some solvers failed: http://www.satcompetition.org/

Comment: @joro: To clarify, I wasn’t sure what you mean by “hard”, and my comments above apply if I read it as “NP-hard”. What happens if one wants it just not to be polynomial-time computable as Joel asked is explained in my answer. Testing SAT algorithms on random CNFs is irrelevant here, because (1) as the name suggests, they are randomly drawn from an exponentially sized pool of instances, so they aren’t given by a deterministic poly-time algorithm, and (2) they just tell you that random k-SAT instances are hard for resolution, on which SAT solvers are invariably based these days.

Comment: Heres's a reference that seems relevant: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X07001072

Comment: @EmilJeřábek 3-SAT with $m$ variables has at most $8 m^3$ clauses (in any case polynomial). Since the reduction is polynomial, my argument works for any number of clauses. A negative answer to question (2) would mean all 3-SAT instances with $m$ variables are polynomial.

Comment: @joro: There are $2^{8\binom m3}$ different 3-SATs in $m$ variables. You didn’t give any indication how to deterministically pick one.

Comment: @joro: And the reference you just added does not help, it only gives an optimized reduction from factoring. This (1) duplicates Timothy Chow’s answer, and (2) does not generate any specific instances, because you would first need to be able to generate instances of factoring.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I well might be wrong. I just added that poly(m) + bipartite graph gives all orders. For instances of factoring just pick two large primes and multiply them. Do you think random 3 SAT with forced unique solution is easy for sat solvers? (pick a random solution, add the right number of satisfiable clauses to make it unique with high probability).

Comment: @joro: Read the question again. Do you understand the difference between “a polynomial-time algorithm that produces ... on input $n$”, and “pick a random solution”?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I believe the unique "random solution" is hard to find in the resulting SAT instance.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek in the latest edit to the answer I claim that if factoring is not in P then it is possible to generate hard SAT instances of any size. In short what is wrong with this claim ("game" in the answer)?

Comment: What is wrong is that you are supposed to compute an instance by a deterministic polynomial algorithm. Such an algorithm cannot “pick two random primes” (or pick random anything, for that matter).

Comment: The original question did not actually specify that the algorithm need be deterministic.

Comment: @SamHopkins: By definition, a “polynomial-time algorithm” means a deterministic Turing machine running in polynomial time. This is a perfectly standard terminology in theoretical computer science. If you want your algorithms nondeterministic, alternating, randomized, heuristic, nonuniform, quantum, interactive, or whatnot, you have to say so.

Answer (score 0):

Random Ninth degree graphs get incredibly hard but solvable, four colorable, as N grows.
Random Fifth degree graphs get incredibly hard but solvable, three coloring, as N grows.

Comment: theory says 16th degrees are five colorable.  but practically unsolvable.