# Surprising mathematical consequences of of $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{NP}$

Tags: computational-complexity

I got interested in the mathematical consequences of $P = NP $ after reading this post, [Any important consequences with presupposition of P≠NP](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278922/any-important-consequences-with-presupposition-of-mathbfp-neq-mathbfnp) .

Wang conjectured that if a finite set of Wang tiles can tile the plane, then there exists also a periodic tiling. This conjecture implies the existence of an algorithm to decide whether a given finite set of Wang tiles can tile the plane. However, the algorithmic undecidability of tiling problem implies the existence of Wang tile set that tile the plane only *aperiodically*.

I am interested in analogous consequences of $P =NP$ to mathematical fields. I am not interested in consequences to computational complexity theory (such as proof complexity). Ideally, if $P=NP$ then certain object must exist with surprising properties. Here are two examples of results from complexity theory (which I am not interested in): If $P=NP$ then there is a sparse NP-complete set (under Karp reduction). Also, if $P=NP$ then there is a short certificate that a graph is not Hamiltonian.

> What are the consequences of $P=NP$ to other areas of mathematics?

Comment: You might be interested in reading Freedman's paper ["Complexity classes as mathematical axioms"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.0033.pdf), though it's not a literal answer to your question.